# DNS Entry for an OpenShift V3

Tags: dns, openshift

I've recently bought a domain name, and I'm trying to redirect this domain name to an OpenShift v3 web app. (It is my first time setting up things like this, so bear with my ignorance.) Normally, OpenShift provides a hostname, something like:

```
myapp-myproject.preview.openshiftapps.com
```

Based on conversation with support of my domain name registry company (not GoDaddy), I need to have some static IP from my Web Hosting provider to add to the DNS Entry or NameServer to link to my domain name (in my domain name account page). It looks like they don't have a clue that PaaS company like OpenShift don't provide a static IP for hosted Web applications.

What I did, is to get the above URL from OpenShift and add this DNS entry as CNAME type, which still didn't work.

Anyone here who has an idea, what I should get from OpenShift in order to tie my domain name and web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CNAME approach should be used. You don't need a static IP address in that case but would use the FQDN of the OpenShift ingress point. You then also need to expose the service in OpenShift via your FQDN and not let it use the generated one.

If you are using the OpenShift V3 developer preview though, I believe use of custom domains is not enabled. The only way I know to have custom host name with the developer preview is to use a proxy service in front.

BTW, do note that the developer preview only provides you a time limited account. You should not use it for real web sites.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I see how to use a proxy in front for starter tier?