# Using a custom domain with openshift v3

Tags: openshift

I've been trying to use Openshift Online v3 to host a web app. It works fine with the red hat-provided domain, but I can't get the routing working to get it to work on any other domain. all I get is:

Application is not available

The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.

Possible reasons you are seeing this page:

```
The host doesn't exist. Make sure the hostname was typed correctly and that a route matching this hostname exists.
The host exists, but doesn't have a matching path. Check if the URL path was typed correctly and that the route was created using the desired path.
Route and path matches, but all pods are down. Make sure that the resources exposed by this route (pods, services, deployment configs, etc) have at least one pod running.
```

Does anybody know how to do a custom domain in Openshift v3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DNS Entry for an OpenShift V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41760436/dns-entry-for-an-openshift-v3)

Comment: For reference:  https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/routes.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As was the case with OpenShift Online Developer Preview, the GA free [OpenShift Online starter tier](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html) does not support custom domains. Custom domains will only be available when the full paid tier is available. The only option in the interim is to use a proxy in front. One option is to use Cloudflare as that proxy.

Comment: This was true at the time of writing but since then the Pro plan has become available and it would be great if the accepted answer would actually help us set it up.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I see how to use a proxy in front for starter tier?

Comment: I have the same question. How would I use Cloudflare as a proxy in front?!

Comment: Create a new question about that specific issue of using Cloudflare. But then, not 100% sure how you can do that. No one who has done it in the past has explained how they did it, so don't know first hand.

Answer (score 15):

Step 1: Create two routes in openshift v3 console. One provided default by the `openshift (*.openshiftapps.com)` and create another route with the host name as your domain name.

Step 2: Go to domain registrar and add a `CNAME` record for your domain which points to `*.openshiftapps.com` domain

Wait for the `CNAME` addition to take effect and access your domain name from the browser, now it should get the page loaded properly.

Comment: What kind of certificate did you use? Were you able to get this to work with letsencrypt?

Comment: I tried to install the certificate generated from letsencrypt but openshift always complains about the format of the certificate. I couldn't make it work with letsencrypt. So, I moved to cloudflare now. With this I'm not getting certificate error.

Comment: I also didn't get any letsencrypt certs on openshift. But almost :-) Just in case you're  interested, here's what I've found out so far: https://github.com/schnatterer/gollum-galore#https-custom-domain

Comment: Actually, this post should be marked as the solution.

Comment: @agm, may I know how to create a route in openshift?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these [docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/routes.html).

```
$ oc create route edge --service=frontend \
    --cert=${MASTER_CONFIG_DIR}/ca.crt \
    --key=${MASTER_CONFIG_DIR}/ca.key \
    --ca-cert=${MASTER_CONFIG_DIR}/ca.crt \
    --hostname=www.example.com
```

Comment: I've done this and set the domain to be came pointing to my site (although my service isn't named `frontend`, that should be immaterial), but I get the error (only on the custom domain, not the red hat one).

Answer (score 0):

For starter (free) plan, you may try hidden redirected URL. Some DNS providers provide such service.